# Consul script handler stdout not showing up in logs as documented

Tags: consul

I'm writting a script to be used as a handler in a watcher config in consul.

The [documentation for `script` type hanlders](https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches#executable) states:

> An executable handler reads the JSON invocation info from stdin. [...] Anything written to stdout is logged.

Based on that, I configured a script handler to watch for a k/v event:

```json
  "watches": [
    {
      "type": "key",
      "key": "some_key",
      "handler_type": "script",
      "handler": "/opt/consul/script/key_handler.sh"
    }
  ]
```

And created the script accordingly

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read event_payload
echo "The value of the key is $(echo $event_payload | jq -r .Value | base64 -d)"
```

I changed the value of `some_key` in the consul k/v store and expected to see the stdout output somewhere in the logs. Consul is configured to log in a file and in syslog with a level of info. Here is the relevant part of the config file:

```json
{
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "log_file": "/var/log/consul/",
    "log_rotate_duration": "24h",
    "log_rotate_max_files": 7
}
```

I looked in both syslog (i.e. `journalct -u consul -f`) and consul current log file (i.e. `tail -f $(ls -trd /var/log/consul/* | tail -1)`. Both log facilities are ok and showing current consul activity. But I cannot find any trace of my script output.

If I modify the script and redirect the output to an arbitrary file, I can find the output I'm expecting so the script definitely does its job.

Did I miss anything in the configuration that is preventing these logs to show up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer while I was writing this question and double checking my tests before posting. So I'll just share not to feel I wasted my time.

Watch script handler output is categorized as debug level by consul. I did not find any doc on that (although I might not have tried hard enough...), I inferred that from experiencing with the setting. You need to change the `log_level` to actually see the output.

```
{
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
}
```

An alternative if you don't want to change the global `log_level` is to use `consul monitor`:

```
# Set a token with needed access level if you use ACLs
# export CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN="<your_token>"
consul monitor --log-level=DEBUG
```

This will let you explore the agents logs live with the desired level of output.

Ref: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_log_level